# Load operation locking table in informix

Tags: locking, informix

A process is performing a `LOAD` operation on a table from a file which has more than 5 lakhs rows.
`onstat -k` command shows row locks for the inserted rows, which I think is normal.
Something abnormal which I see is the `onstat -u` result which shows huge locks against this session.

Also other processes which accesses this table are getting `SQLERR` `-245`

My question is why huge insert operations should lock the table? Shouldn't it lock only the rows? The default lock mode for the table is `row`

Informix version is `IDS 11.5`

Comment: Other process get error `-245 Could not position within a file via an index` can be expected because this will depend of set isolation was used at their session and how long take your load transaction. About the locks, sorry, for me isn't clear what you see as abnormal, if is `onstat -u` showing number of locks differ of `onstat -k` (AFAIK there is no situation what this can occur) or if you seeing a table lock .

Answer (score 1):

Are you using DB-Access to perform the LOAD?  There are a number of other tools that can do LOAD, and each has its own implementation — it actually isn't an operation built into the DBMS itself (I won't bore you with the details of why that's the case).

Have you considered using DB-Load instead?  One of its merits is that it can break a big load into manageable transactions — for example, it can commit every 1000 rows loaded.  This reduces the strain on the locking system enormously.

You might also want to consider whether an EXTERNAL TABLE would improve load performance.

Comment: Yes, `LOAD` is done via dbaccess. I am trying to explore `dbload`. But even though it does batch commits, it will lock the table until all the rows are inserted. I have some 1 million rows to be inserted. So still other processes will not be able to access the table, since they use `CR` isolation level.